# How to query mysql from cron script?

Tags: cron, mysql, mariadb

I have the following code in my script:

```
mapfile results < <(mysql --batch -u $DB_USERNAME -p$DB_PASSWORD $DB_DATABASE < query.sql)
```

and it works fine if running from command line. But if running from `/var/spool/cron/root` then `$results` variable contains nothing.

Why and how to fix?

Comment: Paths and environment all change when you run in cron. Use an absolute path for query.sql and any other file you might need.

Comment: Aside from env issues, you should quote your variables.  Unquoted variables are a disaster waiting to happen - see [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)  Also you should probably use a mysql option file (e.g. `~/.my.cnf`, readable only by you) rather than put the password on the command line....any process running on the system can scan the process table (e.g. run `ps` or trawl through `/proc/*/cmdline`) and extract the password.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `command` part of a `crontab` line is interpreted with `/bin/sh`, which supports a simpler syntax, you'll have to wrap your command in a `bash` script, and invoke that script from `command` part.

Also, your environment variables (`DB_*`, `PATH`) and `mysql` setup MUST be manually propagated to your `cron` environment with care.

Comment: Also, you may not want to store the password in an environment variable since usually all processes by all users running on the machine can see it.